# Failing to read value multi-word command line argument in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am working on writing a bash shell script that has 4 command-line arguments. 3/4 arguments are one word and 1/4 is multi-word. I managed to get values for 2 of them, but can't get right values for 3rd and fourth. If I remove multi-work argumnent however, it works.

```
options=$(getopt -l "help,env:,site:,cluster:,cluster-group:" -o "he:s:c:cg:" -a -- "$@")
eval set -- "$options"

while true
do
    case $1 in
        -h|--help)
            showHelp
            exit 0
            ;;
        -e|--env)
            shift
            export environment=$1
            ;;
        -s|--site)
            shift
            export site=$1
            ;;
        -c|--cluster)
            shift
            export cluster=$1
            ;;
        -cg|--cluster-group)
            shift
            export cluster_group=$1
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo $environment
echo $site
echo $cluster
echo $cluster_group
```

When ran `sh b.sh -s S1 -e E1 -c C1 -cg CG1`, output is

```
E1
S1
g
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `getopt` assumes that options listed after `-o` option are single letters.  So your `cg` option should be listed in your `-l` option, since form `getopt`'s perspective, it is a long option.

Comment: `sh` is not the same as `bash`.

Comment: why are you exporting the variables?

Comment: Or you could use a single letter as the short form of `--cluster-group`, e.g. `-g CG1`

Comment: Exporting them so that they can be used by other scripts. Using single letter is not an option for readability & conflict with other option(s) that I may bring in later.

Answer (score 0):

As per `man getopt(1)`: `-o` recognizes only `one-character` options.

```
-o, --options shortopts
              The short (one-character) options to be recognized.  If
              this option is not found, the first parameter of getopt
              that does not start with a '-' (and is not an option
              argument) is used as the short options string.  Each short
              option character in shortopts may be followed by one colon
              to indicate it has a required argument, and by two colons
              to indicate it has an optional argument.  The first
              character of shortopts may be '+' or '-' to influence the
              way options are parsed and output is generated (see
              section SCANNING MODES for details).
```

So in your case ,you could mention only a single letter, something like :`g` after `-o` option for the `cluster-group`.

```
options=$(getopt -l "help:,env:,site:,cluster:,cluster-group:" -o "h:e:s:c:g:" -a -- "$@")
```